# what is solution of $u(x,y) ?$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = 6xy \\ u(0, y) = y, \quad\frac{∂u}{∂x}(1, y) = 0$$

I was thinking about the [D'Alembert formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula), but I don't know  how to apply this formula on this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating according to $ x$, we get

$$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=3x^2y+v(y)$$

for $x=1$, it gives
$$0=3y+v(y)$$

thus
$$v(y)=-3y$$
hence

$$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=3x^2y-3y$$
and
$$u(x,y)=x^3y-3xy+w(y)$$

for $ x=0 $, we find that $ w(y)=y $ and finally

$$u(x,y)=x^3y-3xy+y$$

Answer (score 2):

> Integrate once

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x, y) = 3x^2y + f(y) \tag{1}
$$

where $f(y)$ plays the role of the "integration constant". If you use your second constraint

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(1, y) = 3y + f(y) = 0  ~~\Rightarrow~~~ f(y) = -3y \tag{2}
$$

which then leads to

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x, y) = 3x^2y -3y \tag{3}
$$

> Integrate again

$$
u(x, y) = x^3 y - 3xy + g(y) \tag{4}
$$

I will leave the final step for you to complete